# How do I adjust the page with for mobile using Bootsrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I want to make this page fill out the mobile screen so buttons and text maximizes on this template.

```
<template name="adminClub">
<div class="container">
    <div class="well well-sm">
    <h3>{{clubname}}</h3>
        <a id="plus" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>
        </a>
        <br>
        {{occupancy}}% 
        <input type="text" value="{{visitors}}" id="visitors"> 
        of {{capacity}}
        <br>
         <a id="minus" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span> 
        </a>
    </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

I would like i to look like this (without zomming)

[image]

And not like this.

[image]
Now the div seem to fill out to much of the page with. I have installed twbs:bootstrap 3.3.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you know how to update the `<head>...</head>` section in your html in meteor, add the following in your head:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

Also I noticed you're html structure is a bit incorrect for bootstrap. Try something like this and see if you get any luck:

```
<template name="adminClub">
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12>
    <div class="well well-sm">
    <h3>{{clubname}}</h3>
        <a id="plus" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>
        </a>
        <br>
        {{occupancy}}% 
        <input type="text" value="{{visitors}}" id="visitors"> 
        of {{capacity}}
        <br>
         <a id="minus" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span> 
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change you `class="btn btn-info btn-lg"` by `class="btn btn-large btn-info"` and so the entire width of mobile extends

you also can insert query media to set the CSS in mobile mode

Example:

```
@media (max-width: 767px){

    }
```

[Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/)

Comment: That actually made the buttons smaller.